# Добавить новый ключ в имеющийся уже массив foreach

Tags: php

Использую PHP 7.2
Как добавить ключ 'experience' в имеющийся массив $doctors, если в двух foreach ключи одинаковые??

```
foreach($html_base->find('a[class=profile--basic__title]') as $key => $element) {
        $doctors[] = [
            'name' => trim($element->innertext),
            'href' => $element->href,
        ];
    }

foreach($html_base->find('div[class=hotspot hotspot--white]') as $key => $element) {
        $doctors[] = [
          'experience' => $element->innertext
        ];
    }

    var_dump($doctors);
```

То есть мне нужно чтобы далее в переменной doctors было три ключа - name, href, experience.

```
$doctors[] = [
   'name',
   'href',
   'experience'
];
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я все правильно понял, то так должен выглядеть второй `foreach`:

```
$count = 0;
foreach($html_base->find('div[class=hotspot hotspot--white]') as $key => $element) {
    $doctors[$count++]['experience'] = $element->innertext;
}
```

А вообще, что-то мне подсказывает что у вас неправильно организованы циклы и это все можно сделать одним.